# How to link a HTML page to a CSS file when the CSS file is in an upper directory?

Tags: html, css, directory

There is my problem:
Since I had some organization issues with my website, I wanted to arrange my files to a better classification.

Now, the folder tree looks like:

- www

  - ressources

    - images

      - ...
    - css

      - design.css
  - mypage1

    - index.html
  - mypage2

    - index.html
  - index.html

And now I don't know how to link the css file to the pages stored in a folder like the "mypage1" folder.
To start from my C: drive will will produce path errors once online, I tried the "shortcuts to the css file in each folder" solution too, but I think there is a far better way to proceed.
Need some help!

Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look at this [ABSOLUTE VS. RELATIVE PATHS/LINKS](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../ressources/css/design.css" type="text/css" media="all">`

The `..` will go one directory top. Since the html files are in a directory (like `mypage1`), this will go to the parent directory, which is `www`. Then the next that should be done is to pass the directory path to your CSS file, which in your case is `/ressources/css/design.css`.

Comment: Finally, I used the relative path to the files everywhere ("/ressources/css/design.css"). The ".." had sometime a strange comportment, like send me in inexistent directories... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use the link:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../ressources/css/design.css">
```

here, used ../ going back folder..